# An Optimal way to send huge text data across the network

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, xml, networking

I have built a GUI which works through the browser. It has drag-n-drop facilities and it prepares an XML when all the attributes have to initialized to it. I can relate the system similar to this online drawing tool available : https://www.draw.io

Its working perfectly as of now, but there is a problem while saving the XML. As of now, I am dynamically creating a form through Javascript and sending the information in the form of an HTTPRequest. It works well when the XML is small (around 5-6 Mb in size).

Off late, the XML size has increased several folds (around 80-100 Mb) and the GUI hangs frequently due to this. It takes 8-10 minutes to send the data across the network and sometimes the browser shuts down automatically after being unresponsive for long duration, thereby thwarting the efforts that the user has put in to create the XML in GUI.

I am using Java in the controller's end. When the user saves the XML, it is passed through the dynamically created HTML form to the backend which is accessed by a Java Controller. I require a better mechanism since sending the entire 80 Mb XML data as an HTTPRequest is becoming extremely cumbersome. Any suggestions to improve it will be welcome.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: I assume you mean MB (megabytes) not Mb (mega bits) Can you compress the data. That will make it 5-10x smaller.

Comment: I have tried to do it. Is it possible to compress it in Javascript itself ? I tried to process the XML in Java Controller side but it is giving OutOfMemory (Heap Error) exception. Please help me out in this respect.

Comment: If you are getting out of memory errors, either a) you don't have enough memory or b) you are not processing the file efficiently.  Have you tried using a memory profiler to see how the memory is being used?